# check whether the sting is palindrome or not?

Tags: python, if-statement

if yes then print the string is palindrome

code using if else and basic python

Input : malayalam
Output : Yes

Input : geeks
Output : No

Answer (score 0):

def isPalindrome(s):
return s == s[::-1]

s = "malayalam"
ans = is Palindrome(s)

if ans:
print("Yes this is a palindrome")
else:
print("No")